# Google maps API auto complete is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I trying to get the google maps auto complete textview , I have taken resource from http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

I have compiled app , app runs but auto complete is not working !
it is like normal textview !

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/atv_places"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="@string/str_atv_places" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

jsonfile

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class PlaceJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

        JSONArray jPlaces = null;
        try {           
            /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
            jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("predictions");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
         * where each json object represent a place
         */     
        return getPlaces(jPlaces);
    }


    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
        int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> place = null;   

        /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
        for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
            try {
                /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
                placesList.add(place);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return placesList;
    }

    /** Parsing the Place JSON object */
    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

        HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String id="";
        String reference="";
        String description="";      

        try {

            description = jPlace.getString("description");          
            id = jPlace.getString("id");
            reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

            place.put("description", description);
            place.put("_id",id);
            place.put("reference",reference);           

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return place;
    }
}
```

custom autocomplete.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

/** Customizing AutoCompleteTextView to return Place Description   
 *  corresponding to the selected item
 */
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /** Returns the place description corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
        return hm.get("description");
    }

}
```

mainactivity.java

```
   package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
        atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);      

        atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {               
                placesTask = new PlacesTask();              
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }
        }); 
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }  

    // Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
            String key = "key=AIzaSyC6EKDiK_7XGJMd9YZ4ve5dvQ421Xwxx6s";

            String input="";

            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }       


            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";         

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service in background
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Creating ParserTask
            parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }       
    }


    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {            

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {            

                String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
                int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

                // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView            
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);             

                // Setting the adapter
                atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        }           
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

i have generated API key and inserted in mainactivity class, am new for android is there any other sources to learn about this?

Comment: String key = "AIzaSyC6EKDiK_7XGJMd9YZ4ve5dvQ421Xwxx6s";

Comment: did you active“Services” pane of the Google console ???

Comment: hmm yes i solved my issue ! , i generated the browser key with ip address, then i removed ip . it working fine now thanks dudes

Comment: Will it works now? Need to add only Billing Account?