# Google Map v2, Autocomplete is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Every time I try to search a place, my autocomplete doesn't work.

Android Monitor:

[image]

My XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true"
    app:columnCount="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from_label"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/from"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />


    <com.ecs.google.maps.v2.fragment.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to_label"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/to"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />


    <com.ecs.google.maps.v2.fragment.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/load_directions"
        app:layout_columnSpan="@integer/create_account_pane_column_count"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/load_directions" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kixkikx.testzng">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network connectivity permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <!-- Access Google based webservices -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDK1zxUEp38e6sQYzJq6qGNKxdOUqUZR1Y"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.fragment.DirectionsInputActivity"
            android:label="@string/directions_input" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, make sure you enabled both **Google Places API for Android** and **Google Places API Web Service** in your Developer Console. Because sometimes it is the issue why the autocomplete doesn't work. Also, try to use a browser key with this. Reference: [Google maps API auto complete is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321480/google-maps-api-auto-complete-is-not-working)